# is there a way to symmetrize The UV map in the UV Editor?

Tags: texturing, uv

i have a Problem with the UV Editor. I don't know how to get rid of the unwrapping of the Model, so i could unwrap anew. I somehow messed up one half of the UV MAp and can't get rid of this. So i would like to know, if there is a way to symmetrize the messed up side to the good half. I use Blender 2.75 at the current Moment.

Comment: Try unwrapping from top/side/front orthogonal view, it might be symmetrical then.

Comment: I got rid of the Problem, before i got the answer. I separated the halfs, (selected faces + y) mirrored the good one, shove it over and dragged aaaall the verts in it's proper place. Mirrored the good one again and moved it over. Thank you anyways :)

Comment: You could add your own answer to help future visitors find solution for this case as I'm not sure what was *your* way (e.g. what is "shove the good part of model over"). It *seems* though that you could achieve the result with deleting bad part and mirroring good one with Mirror modifier.